# git is not getting installed on RHEL4

Tags: redhat, yum, git

I did

```
 yum install git-core
```

and then 
    git

and i am getting

```
bash: git: command not found
```

What did i miss in above steps?

Comment: Which repository did `git-core` get installed from?

Comment: git.i386  1.5.2.1-1.el4.rf

Comment: Note that yum doesn't exist in RHEL-4, maybe you meant CentOS-4? Also, personally, I wouldn't use/recommend rpmforge ... you're likely to have better luck with EPEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a

yum provides */git

This will tell you which package provides the git command itself.  It's possible your git-core is just a bundle of common libraries and the like rather than git itself.

Comment: cool thanx but i installed it from tar directly in the meanwhile